# C++: Is there a traits class containing various functions to manipulate zero terminated char * and wchar_t * strings?

Tags: c++

For instance, I have just found myself writing the following traits like class:

```
template<class TCHAR> struct sz;
template<> struct sz<char>
{
  static void copy(char *dst, int bufSize, const char *src)
  {
    strcpy_s(dst, bufSize, src);
  }
};
template<> struct sz<wchar_t>
{
  static void copy(wchar_t *dst, int bufSize, const wchar_t *src)
  {
    wcscpy_s(dst, bufSize, src);
  }
};
```

I was wondering whether one really has to write such things or is there anything already written that lets us manipulate strings without caring about `wchar_t` or `char`?

After all, we have:

- `cout` vs `wcout`
- `cerr` vs `wcerr`
- `string` vs `wstring`
- `boost::format` vs `boost::wformat`
- etc ...

Comment: Yes, real answer: use `char_traits` although they have a different interface than yours. My opinion: [ban `wchar_t` and use narrow char only](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/102205/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [`std::char_traits<Ch>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits). In particular, `strcpy(dst, src, n)` can be rewritten into `std::char_traits<Ch>::copy(dst, src, n)`.

It doesn't have everything you requested though. Just the standard C string functions are available inside.

For `string` vs `wstring`, you could use `std::basic_string<Ch>`, which is what these two typedefs actually are. Similarly, we have `boost::basic_format<Ch>`.